# Text rapping around floated element is not working in FF

Tags: css, text, word-wrap

I have a problem with text and the wrapping of it around a floating element.

In IE it does it correct and how I want it and in FF it is acting weird...
In FF, the text is wrapping too soon and the surrounding `div` is not expanding like you would expect.

I have searched high and low and tested myself blue, but no result. Does someone know how I can fix this so it is behaving like it should in FF also? I know I can solve it by setting widths, but I want a dynamic layout (if it's possible...)! Code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <table style="border:2px solid steelblue;overflow:hidden;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100%;">
        <div id="page_content" style="float:left;background-color:#ffffff;">
          <div style="float:right;border:1px solid red;">
            ROTA FLOATED RIGHT
          </div>
          <p style="margin:0;border:1px solid green;">
            This is just a stupid text to show my point...
          </p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `1.` What is that table for? I advise against using tables for page design. `2.` Is there a reason for you to be using XHTML strict, and not HTML5? `3.` All CSS should go in a stylesheet - and not mixed in the HTML.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/Bgcxd/ (working as expected in Chromium and Opera, but not Firefox#)

Comment: @ANeves The table is part of my overall design in a real project where this problem stems from. Doesn't matter, same problem without table. And of course css should go in stylesheet, but I'm just trying to show my problem here as compact and easy as possible, to see and reproduce.

Comment: @ANeves (lol, funny rules here... Comments are only allowed to be edited the first 5 minutes.. So here's my new comment!) 1. The table is part of my overall design in a real project where this problem stems from. Doesn't matter, same problem without table. 2. HTML5 is still in development, isn't it? I admit i didn't pay much attention to it yet though... 3. Of course css should go in stylesheet, but I'm just trying to show my problem here as compact and easy as possible, to see and reproduce.

Comment: @user1699857 `2.` HTML5 is still in development, yes, with different levels of early adoption by different browsers. But try `<input type='number'>` in Chrome, `<input type='email'>` in Firefox, and `<progress title="20%" max="100" value="0">20%</progress>` in either. And then try them in IE 8. Using "progressive enhancement" really improves your webpages. (And you can use feature detection to improve these, when they are not supported.) Useful: http://developers.whatwg.org/ (Try the search box on the top-right of that site.)

Comment: @ANeves Some good info here! Thanks. I kind of just want to say "But I just want to wrap the god damn text good!", but I won't... :) I will certainly look into HTML5 and how it can improve my site. And how can i give someone points for good comments? Probably need more points...

Comment: @user1699857 [One can't get points for good comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). I'm glad it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Just put the 'float:left' in your 'p' tag like this.

```
<p style="margin: 0px; border: 1px solid green; float: left;"> This is just a stupid text to show my point... </p>
```

Implement this one one and get the result as same in all the browsers

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
<table style="border:2px solid steelblue;overflow:hidden;">
        <tr>
            <td id="page_content" style="background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid green;">
                        This is just a stupid text to show my point...
            </td>
            <td style="border:1px solid red;">
                ROTA FLOATED RIGHT
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>​
```

Comment: That emulates the erroneous behavior in Firefox for any other browser. But the OP want to get rid of this behavior.

Comment: @LifeIsShort This creates 2 columns in table row. I want the text to wrap around the floating div. Floating the p tag is also not what i want. Using style display:inline on the p tag is a solution, but it involves using padding, which I also want to avoid if possible... To be continued!